# Unique continuation of a solution to ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following initial value problem

$x’(t)=f(t,x(t))$ , $x(t_0)=x_0$ , $x(t) \in \mathbb{R^n}$

This problem satisfies all the conditions of Picard-Lindelöf theorem so it has a unique solution on an interval $[t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon]$.
Eventually, this IVP has a unique solution on $(-\infty,\infty)$ as its solutions are always inside a compact space $D \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ (closed finite space in $\mathbb{R^n}$) and can’t leave it. This is what I deduce logically)

My big problem is that I can’t seem to find an appropriate theorem from a book that states something about **unique continuity of solutions** or maybe a theorem states about solutions to such IVP’s in **compact space that are unique** for all times. I did find this http://mathonline.wikidot.com/continuations-of-solutions-to-first-order-odes in a book I have but doesn’t assure unique continuity…

If such theorems exist, please share with me where can I find them. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "compact space" here?  $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact.

Comment: Well in my case it is $n=2$. What happens here is if we suppose that $x(t)=(A(t),B(t))$ then the solution curve is inside a closed triangle in the $(A,B)$ plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy-Lipschitz (or Picard-Lindelöf) theorem states local existence and uniqueness of solutions, in the case in which $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is locally Lipschitz. In this case, in order to show that the solutions can be (uniquely) prolongated up to $+\infty$ (i.e. that the maximal solution is defined on the interval $(t_0,+\infty)$, property sometimes called forward completeness) one should avoid explosion in finite time. This can be done in several ways, some examples:

- Showing that a certain compact set is forward invariant and attractive: in this case solutions starting inside the set will always stay inside it, and thus they are globally defined (as it seems in your case), the solutions starting outside are converging to it. (Very roughly speaking)
- Providing a linear upperbound on the norm  of the vector field $f$ w.r.t. $x, then applying a comparison argument, like Gronwall Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality.

If one also want completeness backward, similar arguments can be applied backward, mutatis mutandis.

Hope this can help, the result ``no explosion $\Rightarrow$ completeness of solution'' is kind of standard and can be found in any introductory course on differential equation.

Comment: But this is exactly what I’m asking. I know that any solution stays inside such set and can’t leave. But how can I know that they are globally defined? On which theorem is this based on? That is my question.

Comment: A random reference with proof is the following http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/GU/MMG511/V16/Extension_lecture_notes.pdf, see Theorem 6.

Comment: But I think this ''escaping the compacts sets'' argument can be found in any differential equation book containing the existence and uniqueness argument.

Comment: Well, from the proof of this theorem, then the uniqueness of the extension is assured because of the Lipschitz condition right?

Comment: Yes, uniqueness is implied by the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem....indeed local uniqueness implies the global one: suppose by contradiction  that there is a non-unique way of prolongate a solution, then there is a bifurcation, and at this point we are negating the local uniqueness ensured by Cauchy-Lipschitz, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: I see, makes sense logically. I guess now what I need to keep looking for a book that states this more or less. I do have some ancient books but they take unnecessarily difficult paths and I was pretty sure it shouldn’t be that way.

Comment: I’m extremely grateful for this link! :) No matter how much I searched, I couldn’t find something like this. Maybe my wording did not help me in finding it. What this something you did find in Google?